# Add UserGroup to a Role using LocalServiceUtils - Liferay 5.2.3

Tags: java, liferay, roles, usergroups

I'm looking for a way to add an usergroup to a role. I couldn't find a solution in the API or liferay forum.
Is something like that possible for usergroups?

```
GroupLocalServiceUtil.addRoleGroups(portalrole.getRoleId(), grouplist);
```

It only works for groups. RoleLocalServiceUtil, UserGroupLocalServiceUtil and so on don't have some methods like this.

environment:
Liferay. 5.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in this way

```
UserGroup ug = UserGroupLocalServiceUtil.getUserGroup(PortalUtil.getCompanyId(request), "your_user_group_name");

long [] ugIds = {ug.getGroup().getGroupId()};

GroupLocalServiceUtil.addRoleGroups(yourRoleId, ugIds );
```